# How to get old "windowing" behavior in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Remember this button?

[image]

It used to turn a full-screen app into a window that's smaller than your screen. Trivial, right?

Well, in Windows 10 it just doesn't do anything. Neither is double-clicking on the top of the window. They just broke ('revamped') the whole basic "Windows" experience for me.

I know they meant well and there is a "new and improved" windowing system, which I dislike and don't fully understand.

Is there a way to get the old windowing/maximize/unmaximize behavior back?

Comment: It seems there may be something wrong with your system, because the button you point out does the exact same thing it used to in Win8.1/8/7. The only difference is the animation that goes about doing it. Further, double-clicking on the top of the Windows behaves the same way, i.e. it alternates between maximize and windowed.

Comment: Have you tried different apps? Also, sometimes an app's "restored" size just so happens to fill the entire screen such that it *appears* maximized when it actually isn't. In that state you only need to drag the window across a bit so that you may resize it yourself.

Comment: I know about dragging. It doesn't work. This happens with all apps I've tried, I believe (e.g. notepad).

Comment: See also on Quora: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-Windows-10-look-behave-like-Windows-7